# How to configure Solr autosuggest to show result based on first word of user query instead of last?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

[image: When typing first word:]

[image: When typing second word:]

The desired case: to have only "pants" based results after "belt" typing.

Comment: this is because of the tokenizations....do not tokenize the text...use the keyword tokenizer and lowercase filter factory as fieldType and use it for your field....

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti sorry, I'm very new to Solr. Could you, please, give me a hint, where to adjust this configuration? I assume it is not possible in backoffice..

Comment: @endurance2296 Abhijit is talking about your `schema.xml`, specifically the `tokenizer` [configuration]((more info [here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/tokenizers.html))) for the field you're getting your suggestions from. More often than not a tokenizer that splits text by spaces/dots/etc is used (it's the case of the `StandardTokenizer`). Abhijit's suggestion is for you to use the `KeywordTokenizer` instead, which does not have this behavior and treats the full field as a single token. With the information you provided this will probably work for you.

Comment: @nitrin0 thank you! Now I understand the concept. After applying the changes, I probably have to reindex full configuration?

Comment: If you have the tokenizer applied at index time (inside a analyzer of type `index`) most assuredly yes, you'll have to re-index everything.

Comment: You'll probably want to look at a shinglefilter unless you only want exact hits; the shingle filter will give you separate tokens for tokens that follow each other instead of having to match the whole result